# Why are cryfs encrypted file sizes too big?

Tags: encryption, encfs

I encrypted a 1GB folder using **[Cryfs](https://www.cryfs.org/)** and the encrypted folder appeared to be **6** times larger than the original folder? I know encrypted files are always larger than the original files, but 6 times?!?

Is it a bug causing this or is it normal for CryFs as it does a lot than encfs or any other encrypting apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of CryFS is not only to keep file contents, but also file sizes, metadata and directory structure confidential.

To hide file sizes, CryFS splits the content of a file into same-size blocks and encrypts these blocks individually. A tree structure is used to remember how the blocks belong together to form a file. This tree structure has very little overhead and itself is also stored using encrypted same-size blocks. To hide file metadata and directory structure, they are also represented using encrypted same-size blocks.

Source:

https://www.cryfs.org/howitworks

Comment: Appreciate your contribution

Comment: Always [eager to help!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help) Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Following is directly from the developer, Sebastian M. : (hope this helps somebody who has the same question)

> tldr;> This can happen due to how CryFS works, but should be much
>   better in the upcoming 0.10 release series. You can also improve it
>   when using a 0.9.x version by changing the block size of your file
>   system.
>
> Background: CryFS 0.9.x allocates all data in blocks of 32kb by
>   default. Even if you have very small files, each file needs at least
>   one block and will need at least these 32kb of space. This is done,
>   because CryFS uses this to hide the file size. You can read more on
>   why this is important in the second paragraph here:
>   https://www.cryfs.org/comparison#encfs There is a security proof in
>   the CryFS paper that attackers cannot find out your directory
>   structure or how large your files are from seeing the encrypted file
>   system.
>
> But unfortunately, this means that in scenarios where you store a huge
>   number of tiny files, the bloat can be quite a lot. In 0.10.x, the
>   default was changed to using 16kb blocks, so the bloat should be much
>   smaller. However, you don't need to wait for that. When creating a
>   file system, you can choose the block size. Choosing a smaller block
>   size will reduce the binary bloat (you can try going down to 4kb), but
>   might make the file system a bit slower when accessing large files.

Comment: Wow. I have already been waiting for over 24 hours to rsync between two drives that can sustain >50MB/s when doing a drive to drive rsync and I'm barely getting 2MB/s due to small file size; it's driving me out of my mind!!! And I'm supposed to think the solution is SMALLER files? Why not just pack multiple files into one block???

Comment: @Michael: Or pack multiple blocks into one file. Like, allocate all data in blocks of 4kb, then put 64 of them into one file.